# Downloading a file in android kotlin gives no error but when trying to find or access it the file does not exist

Tags: android, file, kotlin, caching, download

I am trying to create a pdf file downloader in my app, downloading pdf files from firebase database, and storing them in the app's folder. The download itself gives no errors, but when I try to access the file it immediately crashes the app and gives me an error "null reference". I have tried debugging it to only open the file if the file exists, I have tried manually going into the app's folders(under android/data/myappsname/files) but even the directory which I create in the code does not show there, nothing shows there.

My code for downloading looks like this:

```
fun downloadPDF(name : String, onDownloadComplete:  (pdfFile : String) -> Unit){
    checkIfFileExists()
    val downloadReference = MenuBarDatabaseFacade.databaseSingleton.getDownloadPDFReference(name)
    var downloadProgress : Long
    val saveFile = File("$pdfFolderPath/$name")
    if(!saveFile.exists()){
        saveFile.createNewFile()
        downloadReference.getFile(saveFile).addOnSuccessListener {
            onDownloadComplete(name)
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.removeFile(saveFile)
        }.addOnProgressListener {
            downloadProgress = 100 * (it.bytesTransferred / it.totalByteCount)
        }
    }else{
        onDownloadComplete("$name")
    }

}
```

The database reference is taken from here:

```
fun getDownloadPDFReference(fileName : String) : StorageReference{
    Log.d("file name", "$fileName.pdf")
    var downloadFileReference = storageRef.child("$fileName")
    val downloadTask = downloadFileReference
    return downloadTask
}
```

The path is initialised from the MainActivity here:

```
FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.init(filesDir.toString())
```

And here is the init in FileManager

```
fun init(cacheDirectory : String){
    filePath = cacheDirectory
    jsonPath = "$filePath/savedMaterials.json"
    pdfFolderPath = "$filePath/downloads"
    Log.d("path", jsonPath)
    Log.d("path", pdfFolderPath)

}
```

When I check if the file exists I also create the directories if they do not exist right here:

```
fun checkIfFileExists(){
    if(!File(jsonPath).exists()){
        File(jsonPath).createNewFile()
    }
    if(!File(pdfFolderPath).exists()){
        File(pdfFolderPath).mkdirs()
    }
}
```

The download function is called here:

```
 fun openMaterial(position : Int)
{
    val parent = parentFragment as MenuViewController
    FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.downloadPDF(Materials[position].getURL(), onDownloadComplete = { materialName : String ->
        parent.openPdf(materialName)
    })
}
```

And then finally the pdf is opened here:

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var view = inflater.inflate(com.madortilofficialapps.MedicBook.R.layout.fragment_pdf_view, container, false)
    var url = arguments!!.getString("name")
    if(FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.getFile(url!!).exists()){
        try{
            pdfView.fromFile(FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.getFile(url!!))
        }catch (e : Exception){
            Log.d("PDFView", "Getting error: " + e.localizedMessage)
        }
    }
    return view
}
```

The file path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.madortilofficialapps.MedicBook/files/downloads/filename.pdf

The getFile function is here:

```
fun getFile(name : String) : File{
    if(File("$pdfFolderPath/$name.pdf").exists()){
        Log.d("exists", "exists")
    }
    return File("$pdfFolderPath/$name.pdf")
}
```

I think this is pretty much it. As I mentioned above I do not get any error downloading the file, but get a null reference when trying to access it, and when trying to go into the folder manually cannot even see the directory.

Comment: @blackapps The pdffolderpath is initiated in the mainactivity using "filesDir.toString()", so it is essentially filesDir.toString()/itemname.pdf

Comment: @blackapps debugging shows me the path is:  /data/user/0/com.madortilofficialapps.MedicBook/files/downloads/מכשירי החייאה.pdf

Comment: @blackapps I am using api 29, as for device I tried both on my physical phone(android s9), and on the vm Pixel 2 XL(API 28 android 9)

Comment: `I have tried manually going into the app's folders(under android/data/myappsname/files)` Well that is a different path as there is no `android` in that path. Further file explorers have no access to your apps private directory. But the file explorer of Android Studio has.

Comment: I see, is there any way I can get the path of those files pragmatically(I don't want to manually add a path string since some phones might be different)

Comment: Log the value of File.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: @blackapps Ok I managed to save it where I can see it and it seems that the problem is not the saving, which works fine, but the pdf reader(bartesk) seems to crash saying that the file it is getting is a null object reference

Comment: Are you referring to pdfView.fromFile(FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.getFile(url!!)) ? If so then tell the value of uri.toString() and the value of the string FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.getFile(url!!).getAbsolutePath() returns. I asked you before to put all paths in your post next to the code.

Comment: @blackapps

FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.getFile(url!!).getAbsolutePath() returns /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.madortilofficialapps.MedicBook/files/downloads/העור.pdf

and url.toString() returns העור.pdf

I tried checking if the file exists using File(FileManager.fileManagerSingleton.getFile(url!!)).exists() before trying to open it, and it still attempts to open it and crashes saying its a null reference. In addition I tried going into the pdf file manually(going to storage and opening it), and it works fine, so the file is not corrupted or something

Comment: Do the check before you try to open the file. Add all to your code so we can see what you do.

Comment: @blackapps I updated the code in the main post of where the pdf is opened. When I open it I catch this error:

D/PDFView: Getting error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView$Configurator com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.fromFile(java.io.File)' on a null object reference

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry... Dont know why his goes wrong...

Comment: I just found the problem. For some reason I .eeder tobreference the pdf view and use that instead of using the original one.